# No padding by default on Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner with this code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/cover_hint"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Yet for some reason when it's first loaded (I am loading items in from an `ArrayList<String>`), it appears too small. Like the first image below. But once I select an item, then it appears normally like in the second image.

How can I get it to always appear like the second image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing the height with

```
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

That worked for me after I tried other things like `android:padding` and `android:textSize`, neither of which seemed to have an effect.